# Only show decimal portion of Double with the decimal point

Tags: ios, swift, double

I'm trying to only show the decimal portion of a number but it keeps printing the number with the decimal point:

for number 223.50:

```
changeAmountLabel.text = "\(balance.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1))"
```

this will print .5, but what needs to be printed is 50, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Convert it to string and remove the part before the decimal point. That's the only way to do it.

Comment: @Sulthan How would you be able to do that without the decimal point?

Comment: @SwiftyJD split by `.` and take the ending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a `NumberFormatter`.

Try this:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3


let number = 223.50
if let str = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number)) as? String {
    if let range = str.range(of: ".") {
        let value = str.substring(from: range.upperBound)
        print(value) // 50
    }
}
```

**Update for Swift 4:**

```
if let str = formatter.string(for: number) {
    if let range = str.range(of: ".") {
        let value = str[range.upperBound...]
        print(value) // 50
    }
}
```

Comment: kkkk I won by 3 seconds

Comment: note that if you don't specify the locale "." might be the thousands grouping separator

Comment: You will have to set locale for the formatter or use the decimal separator from the current locale.

Comment: this would result in "00" for integers.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to floor your balance and subtract the result from it,  next multiply it by 100. After that you can format the result as needed:

```
let balance =  223.50
let cents = (balance - floor(balance)) * 100
let formatted = String(format: "%.0f", cents)  // "50"
```